# Php: Group and add missed field

Tags: php, mysql

I have in a array a table like this:

```
cid plugin  lang_id     name    father  
1   Newspage    1   Actualidad  1
1   Newspage    2   News    1
2   Newspage    1   Tecnologia  1
2   Newspage    2   Tech    1
3   Newspage    1   Deportes    1
3   Newspage    2   Sports  1
4   Newspage    1   Ocio    1
```

In this example there are two languages (1:Spanish and 2:English) but admin can add more languages

I want do a "modify category" section and group it by CID with input boxes for each language if language its missed i want display a empty input for add the missed language.

Something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWYvc.png

My actual bad code its this:

```
    $content = "<div class='catlist'>";     
$content .= "<p>{$LANGDATA['L_NEWS_MODIFIED_CATS']}</p>";
$query = $db->select_all("categories", array ("plugin" =>  "Newspage", "lang_id" => 1)); 

while ($cat_grouped = $db->fetch($query)) {
    $content .= "<form id='cat_mod' method='post' action=''>";
    $content .= "<div>";

    foreach ($langs as $lang) {
        if ($lang['lang_id'] == $cat_grouped['lang_id']) {
            $content .= "<label>{$lang['lang_name']}</label> <input type='text' name='{$lang['lang_id']}' value='{$cat_grouped['name']}' />";
        } else {                                   
            $query2 = $db->select_all("categories", array ("plugin" =>  "Newspage", "cid" => "{$cat_grouped['cid']}", "lang_id" => "{$lang['lang_id']}"));
            if($db->num_rows($query2) <= 0) {
                $content .= "<label>{$lang['lang_name']}</label> <input type='text' name='{$lang['lang_id']}' value='' />";
            } else {
                $other_lang_cat = $db->fetch($query2);
                $content .= "<label>{$lang['lang_name']}</label> <input type='text' name='{$lang['lang_id']}' value='{$other_lang_cat['name']}' />";
            }
        }
    }
    $content .= "<input type='hidden' name='cid' value='{$cat_grouped['cid']}' />";
    $content .= "<input type='submit' name='ModCatSubmit' value='{$LANGDATA['L_NEWS_MODIFY']}' />";
    $content .= "</div></form>";
}
$content .= "</div>";
```

This:

```
$db->select_all(...);
```

mean
    $db->select_all("table", $WHERE, ...)

I want to retrieve all content in one query and do the work in php

My  actual code its clearly very bad and assumed `lang_id=1` exists for each entry and do few query's huh!

My old code use "GROUP BY cid" for the first query and not need to use "lang_id=1" but after a system upgrade that line give the error:

reported: Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

and not want to use again that.

any idea the best way for do that?

Comment: I do not know how the others but my response to your question is not clear what you really want. I suggest you interceded input array, and you want to get or output.

Comment: better code, my actual code (i post it) its very bad and involver few querys...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your database library is, so I'm writing a pseudo like code.

First, I would use a pagination to limit the database queries, for example 10/20 phrases for each page. So the query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM language_phrases WHERE cid IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT cid FROM language_phrases WHERE plugin = 'Newspage'
    LIMIT 0,10
)
```

then I would use the data from database first to get the `cid` values:

```
$cid = array();
$strings = array();

while($row = $db->fetch($result))
{
    if(!in_array($cid,$row["cid"]))
    {
        $cid[] = $row["cid"];
    }
    $strings[]= array(
        "cid" => $row["cid"],
        "lang_id" => $row["lang_id"],
        "name" => $row["name"],
        "father" => $row["father"]
    );
}
```

Then I would have the table and the distinct cid's in this page in my buffer. Then PHP will do the rest:

```
foreach($cid as $idx=>$key)
{ 
   $values = array_filter($strings,function($d) use ($key) { 
       return $d["cid"] == $key; 
   });
   // build the form with the $values array.
}
```

Comment: thanks, i made other version more basic (i post it) but will check your code/way later today now need a coffe. :)

Answer (score 0):

This problem give a headache but i made another version that work and only one query.

I will check later the Taha Paksu version/way (thanks!)

```
   $content = "<div class='catlist'>";     
$content .= "<p>{$LANGDATA['L_NEWS_MODIFIED_CATS']}</p>";
$query = $db->select_all("categories", array ("plugin" =>  "Newspage"), "ORDER BY cid"); 

$cats = [];
$catsids = [];
while ($cats_row = $db->fetch($query)) {
    $cats[] = $cats_row;  
    $catsids[] = $cats_row['cid'];
}
$catsids = array_unique($catsids);
$foundit = 0;
foreach ($catsids as $catid) {
    $content .= "<form id='cat_mod' method='post' action=''>";
    $content .= "<div>";         
    foreach ($langs as $lang) {   
        foreach ($cats as $cat) {                    
            if (($catid == $cat['cid']) && ($cat['lang_id'] == $lang['lang_id'])) {
                $content .= "<label>{$lang['lang_name']}</label> <input type='text' name='{$lang['lang_id']}' value='{$cat['name']}' />";
                $foundit = 1;
            }                   
        }
        if ($foundit == 0) {
            $content .= "<label>{$lang['lang_name']}</label> <input type='text' name='{$lang['lang_id']}' value='' />";
        }                   
        $foundit = 0;                
    }
    $content .= "<input type='hidden' name='cid' value='$catid' />";
    $content .= "<input type='submit' name='ModCatSubmit' value='{$LANGDATA['L_NEWS_MODIFY']}' />";
    $content .= "</div></form>";   
}
```